# New registration on openfire with Strophe.js

Tags: javascript, openfire, strophe

I use strophe.js library with Openfire to send and receive XMPP messages in browser. It works fine, but only for users I already have in my contact list - roster.
I need to get the new users registered. i know how to add existing people in my roster but i dont know how to register new users on openfire.

Answer (score 5):

Use [XEP-0077](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html), there already exists a [plugin](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/register) in Strophe's plugin repo.

If not, as a user with admin rights, you need to implement the *Add User* from [XEP-0133](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#add-user). Presumably this would be done on the server.

Finally, there seems to exist the quick and dirty solution of an [HTTP API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html).

Comment: Register-Plugin does not working with OpenFire BOSH Manager https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/issues/93

Answer (score 0):

Using`**strophe.register.js** you can regoster new user on your xmpp server.

https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/register/strophe.register.js