# Methods for new user registration xmpp framework iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, registration

I have developed the XMPP Chat client for iOS and now I'm researching for how to do a new user registration from iOS itself. Can anyone help with the methods used to register a new user. As it needs to communicate with the Server and store the username and password to the server database. Please help I'm searching it from 2 days.

Comment: Mentioning the server you use would make a lot of difference.

Comment: I'm using the OpenFire Server, though I researched on this and the method used for registration in xmpp framework library is          - (BOOL)supportsInBandRegistration;
- (BOOL)registerWithPassword:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)errPtr; But searching for how to implement it.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988206/new-registration-on-openfire-with-strophe-js/10000927#10000927

Comment: hey bro.if you find a solution.please share

Comment: have you find your solution? I am working with same and have same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution HAS WORKED for me

```
NSString *username = @"rohit@XMPP_SERVER_IP_HERE"; // OR [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",username,XMPP_BASE_URL]]
NSString *password = @"SOME_PASSWORD";

AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

del.xmppStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:username];

NSLog(@"Does supports registration %ub ", );
NSLog(@"Attempting registration for username %@",del.xmppStream.myJID.bare);

if (del.xmppStream.supportsInBandRegistration) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![del.xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Oops, I forgot something: %@", error);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No Error");
    }
}

// You will get delegate called after registrations in either success or failure case. These delegates are in XMPPStream class
// - (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender
//- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error
```

Comment: Hey i tried your code but didn't worked for me.I'm unable to connect XMPP to openfire. Please help me knowing how to make this happen. I'm searching for the answer for 1 week but didn't get any help. Please let me know how to configure XMPP. @rohit mandiwal.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you don't already have an account on the server?

Answer (score 10):

```
NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:@"venkat"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:@"dfds"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"eref defg"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"accountType" stringValue:@"3"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"deviceToken" stringValue:@"adfg3455bhjdfsdfhhaqjdsjd635n"]];

[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:@"abc@bbc.com"]];

[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] registerWithElements:elements error:nil];
```

We will know whether the registration is successful or not using the below delegates.

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender{


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Registration" message:@"Registration Successful!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}


- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error{

    DDXMLElement *errorXML = [error elementForName:@"error"];
    NSString *errorCode  = [[errorXML attributeForName:@"code"] stringValue];   

    NSString *regError = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR :- %@",error.description];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Registration Failed!" message:regError delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    if([errorCode isEqualToString:@"409"]){        

        [alert setMessage:@"Username Already Exists!"]; 
    }   
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Hi Karun where you set the host name and the portname?

Comment: hi brother, - (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender method is not calling. how should i check user is registered or not

Comment: You need to check the 'In band Registration' and 'anonymous login' settings in the XMPP server settings. Other wise by default XMPP doesn't support registration from external apps.

Answer (score 0):

New user can register at XMPP server from iOS by two methods as

**Methode 1.)** By In band Registration (In-band registration means that users that do not have an account on your server can register one using the XMPP protocol itself, so the registration stays "in band", inside the same protocol you're already using.) you have to use **XEP-0077** extension.

And your server should also have to support In band Registration.

Use these steps for In band Registration

**step 1:** connect with xmppStream

```
- (BOOL)connectAndRegister
{
    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSString *myJID = @"abc@XMPP_SERVER_IP_HERE"; // OR [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",username,XMPP_BASE_URL]]
    NSString *myPassword = @"SOME_PASSWORD";

    //
    // If you don't want to use the Settings view to set the JID,
    // uncomment the section below to hard code a JID and password.
    //
    // Replace me with the proper JID and password:
    //  myJID = @"user@gmail.com/xmppframework";
    //  myPassword = @"";

    if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
        DDLogWarn(@"JID and password must be set before connecting!");

        return NO;
    }

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
    password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream connect:&error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                            message:@"See console for error details."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

`NSString *password` declare at @interface part of your file

**step 2:** When xmppStream Delegate `- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender` call

**step 3:** Start register via In-Band Registration as

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:XMPPStreamStatusDidConnectNotification
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:nil];
    _isXmppConnected = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;
    DDLogVerbose(@"Start register via In-Band Registration...");

   if (xmppStream.supportsInBandRegistration) {

      if (![xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:&error]) {
           NSLog(@"Oops, I forgot something: %@", error);
      }else {
          NSLog(@"No Error");
     }
  }
//    [_xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error];
}
```

**step 4:** Check registration success or failure by XMPPStream delegate

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error
```

**Methode 2.)** By XMPP Rest Api on the openFire server installed a plugin (Rest Api plugin) that allows normal registration.

Use these steps for Rest Api Registration

**step 1:** Install Rest Api plugin on server

**step 2:** Configure server for Rest Api as server -> server settings -> Rest Api then enable it.

You can use "Secret key auth" for secure user registration, so copy that from openfire server and use when rest api is called for registration.

**step 3:** Call Rest Api for registration

```
-(void)CreateUserAPI
{   
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"abc",@"username",@"SOME_PASSWORD",@"password",@"abc-nickname",@"name",@"abc@example.com",@"email", nil];
    NSData* RequestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@users",RESTAPISERVER]]];


    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:AuthenticationToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setHTTPBody: RequestData];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                // handle response
                if (!error)
                {

                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                    if ([httpResponse statusCode]==201)
                    {

                        NSLog(@"Registration Successful");

                    }else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Registration failed");
                    }

                }else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Try again for registration");
                }


            }] resume];
}
```

`RESTAPISERVER` is a Rest api url string.

`AuthenticationToken` is a "Secret key auth" (copy from openfire server)