# How to Enable user registration - eJabberd for mac?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

i am currently working with xmpp to enable chat.
as
i refer this link: [link 1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958)

so i am sucesfully able to register user from console.
but i want to register username from my application.

i found some links,
 i also find a solution that" enable user registration in control panel".

[Solution of a new user register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257557/methods-for-new-user-registration-xmpp-framework-ios)
here is my trial code

```
NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:@"venkat"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:@"dfds"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"eref defg"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"accountType" stringValue:@"3"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"deviceToken" stringValue:@"adfg3455bhjdfsdfhhaqjdsjd635n"]];

[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:@"abc@bbc.com"]];

[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] registerWithElements:elements error:nil];
```

but not working.

can you please exacly tell me what is the real problem?

Comment: Well, what is not working exactly ? Could you elaborate ? In the code you show, you do not even try to send the packet, so yes, in the current state, the code is partial and cannot work.

Comment: i do not have a single hint how to register user in xmpp.i just found an solution and trying to implement. can you please guide me?

Comment: XMPP user registration protocol is defined in XEP-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are showing cannot work. It is not even sending an XMPP packet.

XMPP user registration protocol is defined in [XEP-0077 - In-Band Registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html). Implementation for XMPPFramework registration is here: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/XEP-0077

You can also use native way to create user in ejabberd, for example with ejabberctl command-line, as described in ejabberd documentation: [ejabberd Post Install Operations](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#post-install-operations).